# limit () and take () not working properly

Tags: laravel

im trying to take 3 most viewed post but its just getting only two I don't know why I have tried limit () method it's not showing anything what am I doing wrong here ,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Movie;
use Livewire\Component;

class MovieBox extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.movie-box',[
            'movies' => Movie::withCount('read_count')->orderBy('reads', 'desc')->take(3)->get(),
        ]);
    }
}

movie box

<div>

  <div class="relative grid grid-cols-3 gap-2 mt-3 user_story md:grid-cols-5">
    @foreach ( $movies as $movie )
    <a href="#create-post" uk-toggle="target: body ; cls: story-">
        <div class="single_story">
            <img src="assets/images/avatars/avatar-lg-1.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="story-avatar"> <img src="assets/images/avatars/avatar-1.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="story-content">
                <h4> {{ $movie->title }}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    @endforeach
    <span
        class="absolute z-10 items-center justify-center hidden p-2 -mr-4 text-xl bg-white rounded-full shadow-md lg:flex w-9 uk-position-center-right"
        uk-toggle="target: body ; cls: story-">
        <i class="icon-feather-chevron-right"></i></span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your render method like this.

```
public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.movie-box',[
            'movies' => Movie::withCount('read_count')->orderBy('reads', 'desc')->limit(3)->get(),
        ]);
    }
```